# How to use a controller in another assembly in ASP.NET Core MVC 2.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

For the sake of modularity, I have created some controllers in different assemblies. Each assembly represents a bounded context (a module, a sub-system, a division, etc.) of the overall system.

Each module's controllers are developed by someone that knows nothing about other modules, and a central orchestrator is about to cover all these modules in one single application.

So, there is this module called school, and it has a `TeacherController` in it. The output of it is `Contoso.School.UserService.dll`.

The main orchestrator is called `Education` and it has a reference to `Contoso.School.UserService.dll`.

My `program.cs` is:

```
    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseKestrel()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
```

Yet for the routes of teacher controller, I get 404. How to use controllers in other assemblies?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Inside the `ConfigureServices` method of the `Startup` class you have to call the following:

```
services.AddMvc().AddApplicationPart(assembly).AddControllersAsServices();
```

Where `assembly` is the instance `Assembly` representing `Contoso.School.UserService.dll`.

You can load it either getting it from any included type or like this:

```
var assembly = Assembly.Load("Contoso.School.UserService");
```

Comment: What nuget package do I need for `AddApplicationPart` ?

Comment: It is in the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll` assembly and has `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` namespace

Comment: See the docs for more info and source code sample  - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/app-parts

Comment: i am getting error while loading assembly. throwing error, cannot load assembly.

Comment: If you reference the assembly you can use `var assembly = typeof(SomeTypeFromTheAssembly).Assembly`

Comment: This is kind of blowing my mind.  It means that `AddMvc` does not traverse the references to other projects.  I've loaded this up and tried it several different ways and in every case I have to `AddApplicationPart` or MVC will not see controllers in another assembly.  Is there any .net core documentation that highlights the fact that you have to do this to load controllers in another assembly?

Comment: FTA above it says `By default MVC will search the dependency tree and find controllers (even in other assemblies). To load an arbitrary assembly (for instance, from a plugin that isn't referenced at compile time), you can use an application part.`  This is clearly not the case however.  It does not search the dependency tree.

Comment: I always put my controllers on their own separate project.... Never had to to this.

Comment: The key for me was the `AddControllersAsServices()` -- Many Thanks!!

Answer (score 69):

For .NET Core 3.0 [the API has been slightly changed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/app-parts?view=aspnetcore-3.0#load-aspnet-core-features) and the easiest way to register controllers from external assembly in `Startup.cs` looks like:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var assembly = typeof(**AnyTypeFromRequiredAssembly**).Assembly;

    services.AddControllers()
        .PartManager.ApplicationParts.Add(new AssemblyPart(assembly));
}
```

Comment: I use the old syntax in .NET Core 3.0, and I still get the results. Could you also provide a link to your answer for further reading?

Comment: Please take a look at the [migration guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#mvc-service-registration). There are 3 new extension methods, although `AddMvc()` should still work fine.

Answer (score 5):

I'm trying to resolve the controllers while migrating legacy unit tests from .NET Framework to aspnet core 3.1, this is the only way I got it working:

```cs
var startupAssembly = typeof(Startup).Assembly;

var services = new ServiceCollection();

// Add services
...

// Add Controllers
services
    .AddControllers()
    .AddApplicationPart(startupAssembly)
    .AddControllersAsServices();
```

If I change the order of the three last lines it does not work.

---

*Avoid doing this for unit testing unless you really have to, i.e. for legacy reasons. If you are not working with legacy code you are probably looking for [integration tests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-3.1).*

Answer (score 4):

FYI, in ASP.NET Core 7, this works `automagically`.

To be more precise, just by the fact that my main server app had a hard reference to a class library with an `[ApiController]` class in a `Controllers` folder, routes on that controller class *just worked*

Comment: Still working in version 8.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with the above answers, I just use a 1 liners as I know the class that is included in the external assembly that I'd like to load.

The bellow sample comes from the ASP-WAF firewall and is used to load reporting endpoints and dashboard web pages in an existing web application in .net Core 3.1.

```cs
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add<Walter.Web.FireWall.Filters.FireWallFilter>();
    options.Filters.Add<Walter.Web.FireWall.Filters.PrivacyPreferencesFilter>();
}).AddApplicationPart(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Walter.Web.FireWall.DefaultEndpoints.ReportingController)));
```

so to answer your question, let's assume that the TeacherController is in namespace Contoso.School.UserService your implementation would be:

```cs
services.AddMvc(options =>
{                
    //any option
}).AddApplicationPart(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Contoso.School.UserService.TeacherController )));
```

or, if you do not have any options then just ignore them and use this:

```cs
services.AddMvc()
    .AddApplicationPart(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Contoso.School.UserService.TeacherController)));
```

If you are not sure about the class in the assembly then us intelisence in your code starting with the namespace and look for a type to use or open object browser in visual studio

Let me know if you have any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Martin above has the answer, thanks. However it is not immediately obvious how you pass an assembly to Startup.ConfigureServices. How I achieved this was... in the code where I create and start the webHost I call IWebHostBuilder.ConfigureServices and give it something containing the assembly (in my case a custom interface called IOutputProcess)

```
            _webHost = CreateWebHostBuilder().ConfigureServices(e => e.AddSingleton(_outputProcess)).Build();
            _webHost.Start();
```

then in my Startup.ConfigureServices I pull that instance back out of the IServiceCollection with...

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        var outputProcess = sp.GetService<IOutputProcess>();
        services.AddMvc().AddApplicationPart(outputProcess.ControllerAssembly).AddControllersAsServices();
    }
```

I doubt instantiating a service provider purely for this purpose is the cleanest way to do things, but it does work. (I'm open to better ideas)

Comment: use a one liner services.AddMvc()  .AddApplicationPart(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Contoso.School.UserService.TeacherController)));