# .NET Core Application link between projects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have recently started a .net core project and I was wondering what the structure of typical projects are like?

I can see in some other web apps that they have things like account.website.com or analytics.website.com. Are these subdomains their own web projects under the same solution?

If so, How do they point the users to these links from app.website.com to account.website.com?

Currently this is the structure of my web project:

- AppOne.Admin
- AppOne.App
- AppOne.ClassLibrary
- AppOne.Data

I am unsure of how to link my Admin to App in terms of using @Url.Action() or RedirectToAction. Is that possible?

Comment: I think you need register controllers from admin in your exposed app which probably is AppOne.App.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47617994/how-to-use-a-controller-in-another-assembly-in-asp-net-core-mvc-2-0?rq=1