# .NET Core Redirect to Controller in another Project under same Solution

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Is it possible to redirect to another project within the same solution in .NET Core without using an absolute url?

I'm asking because I see so many web apps that have billing.website.com that serves billing functionality only and app.website.com that holds most of the application.

I have found [How to use a controller in another assembly in ASP.NET Core MVC 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47617994/how-to-use-a-controller-in-another-assembly-in-asp-net-core-mvc-2-0?rq=1) but it isn't clear on if the users cookie has timed out, where and how should I redirect the user to?

If I have a project that will be under the url account.website.com that handles authentication, how should I set it in my Startup.cs?

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    // Cookie settings
    options.LoginPath = "accounts.website.com";
    options.AccessDeniedPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(AccessDeniedPath);
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
});
```

Comment: There are no solution-controlled relationships when a .Net project is published to a server, that's just for devs to organize their projects in the IDE.  I'd suggest using an config app setting with the full url of the other project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must be the full absolute URL, as regardless of whether the projects exist in the same solution, while running, they are totally separate and distinct web apps. One has no inherent knowledge of how the other is hosted, and indeed, they could be running under any IP, hostname, domain, subdomain and port thereof.

You should handle this via config. Set something like:

```
{
    "LoginURL": "https://accounts.website.com/login"
}
```

And then you can do:

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = Configuration["LoginURL"];
    ...
});
```

Then, you just need to deploy environment-specific JSON or environment variables to override that config value per environment. For example, when developing it might be `https://localhost:44301/login` instead.