# How to use WebApplicationFactory in .net6 (without speakable entry point)

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, integration-testing, .net-6.0

In ASP.NET Core 6 default template moves everything from `Startup.cs` into `Program.cs`, and uses top-level statements in Program.cs, so there's no more (speakable) `Program` class ether.

That looks awesome, but now, I need to test all of this. `WebApplicationFactory<T>` still expects me to pass entry-point-class, but I cannot do this (due to it's name now being unspeakable).

How integration tests are expected to be configured in ASP.NET Core 6?

Comment: You need to extract the service setup into an extension method, then create a startup class in the test project and call those extension methods. Now you can use `WebApplicationFactory<TStartup>` without having one in the app project.

Comment: @abdusco Sounds like a hack. This way I wouldn't see most of my configuration in `Program.cs` (which I assume was the intention behind moving `Startup` there). What you are suggesting is create a new `Sturtup` more or less. But thanks for a workaround, that's at least some way to get it working.

Comment: @abdusco Wait, but I would still need to provide some `TStartup`, wouldn't I?

Comment: You can always put the extension class / Startup class in Program.cs. Regardless without introducing an abstraction, how can you specify which lines in Program.cs belong to application configuration? Well, you extract the app setup into a class and give it a name, which you can later refer to in the test project, which is exactly what Startup class is for.
Minimal API is cool, but its imperative nature makes some things difficult at the moment.

Comment: Also see: https://github.com/martincostello/dotnet-minimal-api-integration-testing

Comment: [Just checked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.testing.webapplicationfactory-1?view=aspnetcore-5.0#type-parameters), `T` in `WebApplicationFactory<T>` doesn't have to be the `Startup` class, just some class in the application assembly is enough.

Comment: It doesn't seem like I need to create those extension methods. Loke you said, any class from Api assembly will do as a type argument. After I specified random class, everything compiled and all services got configured. However, no controllers got added for some reason (I checked, it executes `AddControllers`). Host is starting and I'm even able to receive Swagger json from it, but it doesn't show any controllers and all api actions return 404. I'm a bit lost here.

Comment: That means the endpoint middleware is not working. Or the endpoint discovery can't find the endpoints defined in the app.

Comment: Fixed it with [`AddApplicationPart`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61812350/4312132). Have no idea why it didn't work without it. I used `Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web"` and added `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing`. Those seem to be the only pre-reqisits.

Comment: This problem is already solved in RC1 by generating a `Program` class in the background, allowing you to use `WebApplicationFactory<Program>`. Don't rush to implement a custom solution for something that may be solved by next Wednesday. [This sample](https://github.com/DamianEdwards/MinimalApiPlayground/blob/main/tests/MinimalApiPlayground.Tests/PlaygroundApplication.cs) uses the nightly RC1 bits and works without extra tricks

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The problem is was solved on ASP.NET Core RC1, but as of now (September 20, 2021) the docs are incomplete.

The compiler generates a `Program` class behind the scenes that can be used with `WebApplicationFactory<>`. The class isn't public though so the `InternalsVisibleTo` project setting should be used.

[Damien Edwards' Minimal API sample](https://github.com/DamianEdwards/MinimalApiPlayground/blob/main/tests/MinimalApiPlayground.Tests/PlaygroundApplication.cs) uses [the latest nightly bits](https://github.com/DamianEdwards/MinimalApiPlayground#dependencies). The test web app class is declared as :

```
internal class PlaygroundApplication : WebApplicationFactory<Program>
{
    private readonly string _environment;

    public PlaygroundApplication(string environment = "Development")
    {
        _environment = environment;
    }

    protected override IHost CreateHost(IHostBuilder builder)
    {
    ...
```

In the application project file,`InternalsVisibleTo` is used to make the `Program` class visible to the test project:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <InternalsVisibleTo Include="MinimalApiPlayground.Tests" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

RC1 is feature complete and, judging by previous major versions, it will probably be the first version to have a `Go Live` license, which means it's supported in production.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, this does work, but with `InternalsVisibleTo` added to the api project: https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/23344#issuecomment-921879727 Could you please add it to the answer? Spent some time figuring out why using `Program` fails.

Comment: @МаксимКошевой thanks, I added this

Comment: I am getting error "System.InvalidOperationException : The entry point exited without ever building an IHost". Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72633793/integration-test-with-webapplicationfactory-in-asp-net-core-6

Answer (score 37):

Note that if you are trying to use xUnit and its `IClassFixture<T>` pattern, you will run into problems if you just use the InternalsVisibleTo approach. Specifically, you'll get something like this:

[image]

"Inconsistent accessibility: base class `WebApplicationFactory<Program>` is less accessible than class `CustomWebApplicationFactory`."

Of course you can solve this by making `CustomWebApplicationFactory` internal but it only moves the problem as now your unit test class will give the same error. When you try to change it there, you will find that xUnit requires that tests have a public constructor (not an internal one) and you'll be blocked.

The solution that avoids all of this and allows you to still use `IClassFixture<Program>` is to make the `Program` class public. You can obviously do this by getting rid of the magic no class version of Program.cs, but if you don't want to completely change that file you can just add this line:

```cs
public partial class Program { } // so you can reference it from tests
```

Of course once it's public you can use it from your test project and everything works.

As an aside, the reason why you typically want to prefer using IClassFixture is that it allows you to set up your WebApplicationFactory just once in the test class constructor, and grab an `HttpClient` instance from it that you can store as a field. This allows all of your tests to be shorter since they only need to reference the client instance, not the factory.

Example:

```cs
public class HomePage_Get : IClassFixture<CustomWebApplicationFactory>
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();

    public HomePage_Get(CustomWebApplicationFactory factory)
    {
        _client = factory.CreateClient();
    }
    [Fact]
    public async Task IncludesWelcome()
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.GetAsync("/");
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        string stringResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Assert.Contains("Welcome.", stringResponse);
    }
}
```

Finally note that [Damian Edwards' MinimalAPIPlayground](https://github.com/DamianEdwards/MinimalApiPlayground) was updated to use this approach after we discussed the issue. See this [commit](https://github.com/DamianEdwards/MinimalApiPlayground/commit/2ffc975ee9eddc1587304bad8a88e5620860a392)

Comment: Sounds like a workaround..

Comment: Oh for sure, that it is.

Comment: `public partial class Program {}` works for me and I didn't have to expose internal types using `InternalsVisibleTo`. Here is the link to the docs that mention testing with `WebApplicationFactory` without a `Startup` class: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-6.0#basic-tests-with-the-default-webapplicationfactory

Answer (score 4):

I tried

```
 <InternalsVisibleTo Include="MinimalApiPlayground.Tests" />
```

but no cigar! Removed it and added a partial class to program.cs

```
#pragma warning disable CA1050 // Declare types in namespaces
public partial class Program
{
}
#pragma warning restore CA1050 // Declare types in namespaces
```

amazingly it worked.

Comment: That's strange `InternalsVisibleTo` worked for me (and continues to work in .Net 6 rc2). Your `Program` class is `public`, so maybe this issue is that you added `InternalsVisibleTo` incorrectly. Maybe name of your test project isn't `MinimalApiPlayground.Tests`

Comment: Hi @maxc137, I did change the name, however, I used the name as in "ABC" and not .Tests (presumabaly a namespace), interesting I'll try again, I'm not sure but I think I prefer in startup as it's easier to remember been caught out with this twice now!