# Why is ASP.NET Core 6 not discovering controllers when run from another .NET Core app

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have created an out of the box ASP.NET Core 6 Web API project.

When I launch the project I can see Swagger loaded, displaying a single WeatherForecast endpoint which works when tested.

[image]

However, when I launch the Web API project from another .NET Core app, the controllers are not discovered. Swagger returns the following message for reference. Also manually calling the endpoint Url fails.

[image]

After some investigation into this issue, I found that if I register the WeatherForecast controller manually it will become visible in Swagger and accessible when requested.

[image]

Why is the WeatherForecast controller not being discovered when running the ASP.NET app from another .NET Core App ?

Source Code: [GitHub](https://github.com/TheLegendaryCopyCoder/Embedded-WebServer-Test)

Comment: Looks like it scans only executing assembly and skip others until you specify one

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59121354/124386) covers .NET Core 3; maybe it still applies to .NET 6?

Comment: @RichardDeeming thanks, yes, its similar to the AddApplicationPart code I used to work around the problem. It is concerning that this issue was raised in .NET Core 3 and still has not been properly addressed in .NET Core 6. I wonder now if its an intentional design characteristic or a bug in the .NET Core code.

Answer (score 8):

Using the [answer linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59121354/124386) to by @RichardDeeming I was able to get it to work in .Net 6.  Find `AddControllers` in Program.cs and adapt it to look like this (substitute `TestServiceController` for one of your controllers that is in the target assembly):

```
var assembly = typeof(TestServiceController).Assembly;

builder.Services.AddControllers()
                .PartManager.ApplicationParts.Add(new AssemblyPart(assembly) );
```

Comment: Thank you so so much, banging my head against this for hours today.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried this:

```cs
builder.Services.AddMvc()
                .AddApplicationPart(typeof(WeatherForecastController).Assembly)
                .AddControllersAsServices();
```